# using Linux command line to convert file character encoding

Tags: bash, shell, character-encoding, command-line-interface

How can one change the file encoding from linux (Fedora 20) command line? 
I have a huge CSV file 7GB and I don't wish to open it.

Answer (score 2):

1. open a console window or terminal...
2. to find out the current encoding

`file -bi /path/to/file.csv`

the result should look something like

```
"text/plain; charset=us-ascii"
```

3. now for the conversion:

`iconv -f inputEncoding -t outputEncoding /path/to/input/file.txt -o path/to/output/file.txt`

for example:

`iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 ~/Documents/bigger_not_filtered.csv -o /tmp/utf8_bigger_not_filtered.csv`

Comment: Note that `file` can only give you a best guess for the encoding. You should *know* what your files are encoded in based on some specification or meta data. If you don't and you need charset detection, you need to employ heuristics, or human eyeballing.

Comment: You have to set the output file with the `-o` argument.

Comment: thanks @MarcelPfeiffer, i updated the answer.